# How do I get a count of stored procedures calls in MariaDB 10.2

Tags: mysql, mariadb

How do I get a count of stored procedures calls in MariaDB 10.2? I cannot turn on the performance schema.

Answer (score 0):

I *think* this will provide it (in some versions):

```
SELECT  SUM(IF(variable_name = 'Queries',   variable_value, 0)) -
        SUM(IF(variable_name = 'Questions', variable_value, 0))
    FROM  information_schema.GLOBAL_STATUS
```

Caveat:  This will be the count since MariaDB was started.